# I am getting an incorrect value from a function in my subclass. Did I set up its constructor incorrectly?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class road {

public:
    road(){};
    void setname(string n) {
        name = n;
    };
    void settype(string t) {
        type = t;
    };
    void setspeedlimit(int s) {
        speedlimit = s;
    };
    virtual void print() {
        cout << name << " is of type " << type << " and has speedlimit " << speedlimit;
    };
    string gettype() {
        return type;
    };

    string name;
    string type;
    int speedlimit;
    string owner;
    int lanes;
};

class mainroad : public road {
public:
    mainroad(string o) {
        owner = o;
    };
    virtual void print() {
        cout << owner;
    };
};

class secondaryroad : public road {
public:
    secondaryroad(int l) {
        l = lanes;
    };
    virtual void print() {
        cout << lanes;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    vector<road> v;
    secondaryroad x11(2), rt3(1), rr5(1);
    x11.setname("old farm");
    x11.setspeedlimit(20);
    x11.settype("secondary");
    rt3.setname("the pike");
    rt3.setspeedlimit(10);
    rt3.settype("secondary");
    rr5.setname("wagon trail");
    rr5.setspeedlimit(10);
    rr5.settype("secondary");
    mainroad n1("feds"), s1("state"), ri1("state");
    n1.setname("usa6");
    n1.setspeedlimit(0);
    n1.settype("main");
    s1.setname("montana 5");
    s1.setspeedlimit(100);
    s1.settype("main");
    ri1.setname("rhody 7");
    ri1.setspeedlimit(55);
    ri1.settype("main");
    v.push_back(x11);
    v.push_back(n1);
    v.push_back(s1);
    v.push_back(rt3);
    v.push_back(ri1);
    v.push_back(rr5);
    for (auto x : v) {
        x.print();
        if (x.gettype() == "main") {
            std::cout << "  This road is owned by " << x.owner << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << " This road has " << x.lanes << " lanes\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On run, I receive -858993460 lanes. Beforehand I was having an issue where this number would appear for my speed limit as well. Is the way I've set up my secondaryroad subclass incorrect? Or is the .lanes segment even identifying any number at all? Also, I have all of my variables in the public domain, but I had trouble trying to get the main function to be able to interact with variables owner and lanes. Is this because they don't have constructors within the base class? Sorry for the loaded questions, I'm a bit new to c++ and programming in general.

Comment: Polymorphism only works with pointers or references. Your vector insertions (`push_back`)  are performing object slicing

Comment: Also `l = lanes;` is the wrong way round, it should be `lanes = l;`

Comment: Well changing around the int l and lanes seemed to fix my problem. I forgot to mention that the main code was from my professor though, although I definitely am messing up on polymorphism. Thank you for the help.